# The multiple if condition is not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am working on a code which displays colored buttons matching with the color specified in the text file. However I am facing a problem where only the first 'if' executes after the match with the entry and the 'if' condition specified in the last doesnt gets checked at all.
like, if specified colors are red,blue .Then the output shows just the red colored button.

here's my code

```
if(R)
 {
 document.write('<button style="background-color:red;width:100;height:100" </button>');
 }

else

if(V)
 {

  document.write('<button style="background-color:violet;width:100;height:100"       
  </button>');  }

else

 if(I)
 {
document.write('<button style="background-color:indigo;width:100;height:100" 
 </button>');
 }


 else

  if(B)
 {

 document.write('<button style="background-color:blue;width:100;height:100"  
  </button>');
 }

 else

 if(G)
 {

 document.write('<button style="background-color:green;width:100;height:100"   
  </button>');
  }

  else

  if(Y)
  {

document.write('<button style="background-color:yellow;width:100;height:100" 

</button>');
}


 else

 if(O)
 {
document.write('<button style="background-color:orange;width:100;height:100" 

 </button>');
 }
```

Comment: What are the values of those variables? Do you get any errors in console? Can you do a ```FIDDLE```?

Comment: So you're supposing that javascript will guess meaning of `R`, `I`, `B` and `V` for you? Fortunately, it can not do that yet (hi, SkyNet)

Comment: If you want to do multiple, unrelated tests then you don't want to be using `else` at all. Also: ***code formatting!!***

Comment: for(var loop = 0; loop < str_array.length; i++)

     {
      var R = str_array[loop].match(/^red/gm);

 var V = str_array[loop].match(/^violet/gm);
 

 var I= str_array[loop].match(/^indigo/gm);
  

   var B= str_array[loop].match(/^blue/gm);
 

      var G= str_array[loop].match(/^green/gm);
 

      var Y= str_array[loop].match(/^yellow/gm);
   

     var O= str_array[loop].match(/^orange/gm);

Comment: @Kazzkiq I have used regex to do that. Well It is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS `class`es instead of `style`. Try not to use `document.write` (unless you are using a Single-Page Architecture).  Instead, put into your HTML in the right place:

```
<button id='mybutton' class='colored'></button>
```

and in your CSS file:

```
.colored {
    width:  100;
    height: 100;
    background-color: puce; /* or some other default */
}
```

And then in your Javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
if (button) { button.backgroundColor=calculatedColor(...); }
```

where `calculatedColor` is a function that does the work of the conditions in the `if` statements.

JQuery has shortcuts, but you should use standard Javascript first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print multilple color button then you should not use the `else`. Try this

```
if(R)
{
   document.write('<button style="background-color:red;width:100;height:100"   </button>');
}

if(V)
{
   document.write('<button style="background-color:violet;width:100;height:100"       
   </button>');  
}
if(I)
{
   document.write('<button style="background-color:indigo;width:100;height:100" 
   </button>');
}
if(B)
{
  document.write('<button style="background-color:blue;width:100;height:100"  
  </button>');
}
if(G)
{
   document.write('<button style="background-color:green;width:100;height:100"   
   </button>');
}
if(Y)
{
  document.write('<button style="background-color:yellow;width:100;height:100" 
  </button>');
}
if(O)
{
  document.write('<button style="background-color:orange;width:100;height:100"
  </button>');
}
```

Also document.write replace the previous values so try to append elements

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is written exactly like that. Once the condition matched, the rest is ignored. This is why `else`. Try removing `else`s if you want all conditions evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,**

Please try below... this is modified code lines....

> ```
> if(R)
>  {
>   document.write('<button style="background-color:red;width:100;height:100"></button>');
>  }
> else if(V)
>  {
>   document.write('<button style="background-color:violet;width:100;height:100"></button>');  
>  }
> else if(I)
>  {
>   document.write('<button style="background-color:indigo;width:100;height:100"></button>');
>  }
> else if(B)
>  {
>   document.write('<button style="background-color:blue;width:100;height:100"></button>');
>  }
> else if(G)
>  {
>   document.write('<button style="background-color:green;width:100;height:100"></button>');
>  }
> else if(Y)
>  {
>   document.write('<button style="background-color:yellow;width:100;height:100"></button>');
>  }
> else if(O)
>  {
>   document.write('<button style="background-color:orange;width:100;height:100"></button>');
>  }
> ```

**Thank you,
Vishal Patel**

Comment: What exactly did you modify?